# How to avoid insert data if the day is X in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how to avoid an insert value if the day is Sunday. That can be possible?

I have this table:

```
 Medical_Appointment
    (
            ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
            Appointment_Day DATE NOT NULL,
            Start_Time TIME NOT NULL,
            Patient_ID INT NOT NULL,
            Service_ID INT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    )
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

And

```
Service
(
        ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        Duration VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Medical_Appointment VALUES(NULL, 2017-26-03, 10:00, 1, 2)
```

To get the day of date value, I have the next query:

```
  SELECT DAYNAME(Appointment_Day) AS `Day`
  FROM Medical_Appointment 
  WHERE ID = 2;
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: You could try with a [BEFORE INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) trigger.

Comment: To clarify, do you wish to insert details into Service based on whether or not Appointment_Day is a Sunday?

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
INSERT INTO Medical_Appointment
SELECT NULL,
       2017-26-03,
       10:00,
       1,
       2
FROM tblService
WHERE DAYNAME( 2017-26-03 ) <> "Sunday"
LIMIT 1;
```

Note : You do not need to use tblService with FROM, but you will need to use FROM with a table that has at least one record in it.

Note : If you do not use LIMIT 1 then MySQL will attempt to insert your values as many times as there are records in tblService.